# How do I reformat the data in d3 having values to the key and another values to the value of the key?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a question about data-reformatting in d3.

I have seen many similar questions but I couldn't find this approach yet.

My data is having the configuration like

```
[{name:a,date:1,price:13,1},{name:a,date:2,price:14.5},{name:a,date:3,price:17.4},...]
```

I woudl like to reformat this data as below.

```
[{a:13.1},{a:14.5},{a:17.4}.....]
```

What should I do in d3 to reformat the data from the original to the desired format?

I tried several different nest and rollup and object approaches,
but still couldn't figure this out.

I'm open to vanila javascript approaches as well.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the format of the array data is as follows:

```
var test = [{name:'a',date:1,price:13.1},{name:'a',date:2,price:14.5},{name:'a',date:3,price:17.4}]
```

You should be able to do this with vanilla JavaScript .map function:

```
test.map(function (x) { var y = {}; y[x.name] = x.price; return y; })
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! 
I wonder what y[x.name] is.
it seems like assigning new key name for the object. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yep, that adds a key/property with a name of 'x.name' to the object, and then sets it's value to x.price (and if the property already exists it will just overwrite the existing value). JavaScript allows you to use objects as a dictionary data structure, which gives a lot of flexibility in setting property keys and values dynamically.